# Should I call preventDefault or not ? How to get user agent list of default actions?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent
>   that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its **default action**
>   should not be taken as it normally would be.

But is there a way to know does the browser / user agent have the default action e.g. for ESC keyDown. 
I can't find any property that describes that event have "default action". The `cancelable` is used for different things.

```
console.log(event.cancelable) // retruns true for all keyDown envets
```

P.S. May be the list of default actions is specified by standard? How to find those lists for Chrome, IE, Safari etc...

Comment: You shouldn't call it unless you're preventing the default behavior. There is no such list of default actions, but it is pretty much common sense.

Comment: There's no harm in calling it if there's no default action.

Comment: @StackSlave but it is not enough to use common sense when you develop e.g. UI components. you should know (learn).

Comment: You use it when you know that you want to override the default action. E.g. if you're submitting a form using AJAX, you need to prevent the normal form submission. If you're not overriding something, you just let it happen.

Comment: @Barmar not always my action exclude default. In some cases I could let it happen (do the work after my handler). There is my logic.

Comment: Of course, that's part of your application logic. But you don't need an API to tell if there's a default action, you know it when you're designing.

Comment: @Barmar Problem is that I do not know. There are many different browsers. I even not sure that I know all "default actions" of one Chrome.

Comment: If there's any browser that has a default action that you need to override, call `preventDefault()`. It will be ignored on other browsers.

Comment: If you're not sure, call `preventDefault()` just in case.